# HTML tag is not filling width of screen with css even with width:100%

Tags: html, css

I have the below HTML code:

```
<form class="form" action="search.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="searchBox" name="name" placeholder="Enter name" oninput="search(this.value)">
</form>
```

I want this form to span out the whole width of the window. I am doing this with css below:

```
.form{
  display: block;
  float:left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border:none;
}
```

However, it is not going the full width. It is leaving a small margin on both sides.

[image]

`<form>` is contained in `<body>` with the followinCSSss:

```
body{
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 1150px 950px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: It's probably not the form itself, but the element it is contained in. Perhaps the `<body>`? But it could be the form. There's no way to tell.

Comment: I think it depends on your parent properties. Or if it is just plain page try giving body{margin:0;padding:0;}

Comment: @VarshaDhadge you are right `margin:0;padding:0;` was commented out when I was testing and forgot to uncomment them. Thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this CSS, will work. :)

```
body{
margin : 0px;
padding : 0px
}
```